# Problem 5.2 from David Morin (classical mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

This problem is from Introduction to Classical Mechanics by David Morin:

[image]

and this the answer:

[image]

I cant understand why the highlighted part is obvious (or not obvious)
I have no idea!

Comment: Welcome!  Please consider [typing out the relevant parts of your screenshot](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126).

Comment: Well, try graphing and then  evaluating the integral of  $x^{-k}$ where k = 1/4 or  3/4 ; then graph $V(x)$ for the same values ( n = 2k) .  Then it should make sense.

Comment: Welcome. This is a math question, so, especially if it's closed here, you might consider [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first part, where $0 < n < 1$, the potential has a cusp. Basically, it looks like one wall of a half-pipe at a skate-park.

We know when someone launches of "the lip", he takes a finite time to reach the bottom. The motion is reversible, so it takes a finite time to reach to top (with zero kinetic energy on arrival).

$n=1$ is a linear ramp, also reversible, but this one you should be able use intuition: you can roll a ball up a hill and have to stop at the top, if you're "just right".

The author's intuition fails him for $1 < n < 2$, so you need to check the integral.

To some extent you can use intuition here by saying, "It's like a $1/r^{n=2}$, and the least energetic unbound state takes infinite time escape"....therefor $n=2$ is the boundary; however, that may be misguided. It depends on the math.